# How to remove characters from floats?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
   Idnumber    Ownership    Date
    1            100        2006
    2            >50        2006 
    1            80         2007
    3            NaN        2006
```

The Ownership column is currently of type float. What I want is to create a groupby function on idnumber that returns the maximum for each Idnumber.
The problem is that this is not possible with things like > < or ± in there (error: unorderable types: float() >= str()).

```
  df['Ownership'] = df['Ownership'].astype(str)
  df['Ownership'] = df['Ownership'].map(lambda x: x.strip('± = > + <'))
  df['Ownership'] = df['Ownership'].astype(float).fillna(0.0)
  df['Ownershipadjusted']= df['Ownership'].groupby([df['Idnumber'],df['Ownership']]).max()
```

Will actually not work, since converting it back to float yields an error: could not convert string to float.

```
         df['Ownership'] = df['Ownership'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Does not have the required effect either.
Is there some more direct way to remove symbols from a float, or make this conversion work ?

To avoid confusion, this is what I need:

```
 Idnumber    Ownership    Date      Ownership adjusted
    1            100       2006      100
    2            50        2006       50
    1            80        2007      100
    3            0         2006        0
```

Of course the dataframe contains far more than 4 observations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cast the `dtype` to `str` and then [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract) the numbers and cast the `dtype` back to `float`:

```
In [215]:
df['Ownership'] = df['Ownership'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
df

Out[215]:
   Idnumber  Ownership  Date
0         1        100  2006
1         2         50  2006
2         1         80  2007
3         3        NaN  2006
```

Also your `groupby` statement is wrong you need this:

```
In [218]:
df['Ownershipadjusted']= df.groupby(['Idnumber'])['Ownership'].transform('max')
df

Out[218]:
   Idnumber  Ownership  Date  Ownershipadjusted
0         1        100  2006                100
1         2         50  2006                 50
2         1         80  2007                100
3         3        NaN  2006                NaN
```