# Pandas: convert column with empty strings to float

Tags: python, pandas

In my application, I receive a pandas DataFrame (say, `block`), that has a column called `est`. This column can contain a mix of strings or floats. I need to convert all values in the column to floats and have the column type be `float64`. I do so using the following code:

```
block[est].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
block[est].astype('float')
```

This works for most cases. However, in one case, `est` contains all empty strings. In this case, the first statement executes without error, but the empty strings in the column remain empty strings. The second statement then causes an error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float:`.

How can I modify my code to handle a column with all empty strings?

**Edit**: I know I can just do `block[est].replace("", np.NaN)`, but I was wondering if there's some way to do it with just `convert_objects` or `astype` that I'm missing.

**Clarification**: For project-specific reasons, I need to use pandas 0.16.2.

Here's an interaction with some sample data that demonstrates the failure:

```
>>> block = pd.DataFrame({"eps":["", ""]})
>>> block = block.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
>>> block["eps"]
0
1
Name: eps, dtype: object
>>> block["eps"].astype('float')
...
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove characters from floats?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460075/how-to-remove-characters-from-floats)

Comment: I don't think so. I'm having problems here specifically with empty strings, not with modifying non-empty values.

Comment: could you please post a few lines of sample data?

Answer (score 34):

It's easier to do it using:

> pandas.to_numeric
>
> http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'eps': ['1', 1.6, '1.6', 'a', '', 'a1']})

df['eps'] = pd.to_numeric(df['eps'], errors='coerce')
```

'coerce' will convert any value error to `NaN`

```
df['eps'].astype('float')
0    1.0
1    1.6
2    1.6
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: eps, dtype: float64
```

Then you can apply other functions without getting errors :

```
df['eps'].round()
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: eps, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_float(val):
    try:
        return float(val)
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'eps': ['1', 1.6, '1.6', 'a', '', 'a1']})
>>> df.eps.apply(lambda x: convert_float(x))
0    1.0
1    1.6
2    1.6
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: eps, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Doesn't work with my version of pandas: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: Sorry, that is the name I gave the column.  That should be eps per your example.

Comment: This replaces valid data with NaN, which is not what I'm looking to do. E.g., if my DataFrame contains ["", "1.0"], the "1.0" is also converted to NaN.

Comment: That's why sample data goes a long way.  Could you please post some?