# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '' "

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the column-`TRADE` in my CSV file to float values. They are presently of type string.

```py
df.TRADES.astype(float)
```

which gives me an error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

I have attached my CSV file. Do I fill the empty cells with some data to mitigate this error?

[image: img]

Comment: could you give us all the data from the csv file?

Comment: The error message says you have an empty string where a float is supposed to be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: convert column with empty strings to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465741/pandas-convert-column-with-empty-strings-to-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string `''` in your `TRADES` column. I suggest looking into the record with this value, but — if you're certain that all values in `TRADES` are correct as they are — you can use the `pd.to_numeric` function to convert to float:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.to_numeric(df.TRADES, errors="ignore")
```

Values that cannot be parsed (i.e., `''`) will be set as `NaN`.